# Using 2008, how do I add the rich textbox?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using 2008, how do I add the rich textbox to my toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Toolbox -> Report Items -> Text Box?  If you had it before and now it is missing, then right click on Report Items -> select Reset Toolbox, and it should flow through.  If you are referring to the ASP.NET RichTextBox control, it isn't part of SSRS and can't be used in a report.